# C# console.write showing statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, console.writeline

This is part of my code and I'm trying to make console.write to show new statement of "Please re-enter number greater than 20 : " only.

The problem is when I run my code it show "Please re-enter number greater than 20 : " as well as  previous statement ("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : "). in one line.

How can I make it not to show first write statement ??

```
static double InputFuel()
    {
        double fFuel;
        string text;
        bool badValue = true;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(text, out fFuel) && fFuel >= 20)
            {
                badValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0} is below the minimum value of 20  \n\n", text);
                Console.Write("Please re-enter number greater than 20 : ");
            }
        } while (badValue);
        return fFuel;
    }//end InputTemp
```

Comment: Console.Clear()  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you only want to show the "Enter amout of fuel" message once then don't put it in the loop.

Comment: `"How can I make it not to show first write statement"` - By removing the first write statement?

Comment: I want the first statement to show up first but if user type wrong input I want second statement to show only

Comment: Just use \r instead, when you print your next statement, so that it returns to the start of the line and overwrite your original write. You don't need to clear the console for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the line `Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");` outside the while-loop. In your example it is inside the while loop, so it is repeated every time an incorrect answer is entered. If you move it in front of the loop, it will only be written once to the console.

```
...
bool badValue = true;
Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");
do
{
    text = Console.ReadLine();
    ...
```

Comment: Yes stupid me, I wasn't thinking that it was in loop

Comment: @C.Knight if it is outside the loop, how would it display the same line of text multiple times?

Comment: @lufee: No worries. If you think this was the right answer, please confirm it by clicking on the gray tick on the left of the answer, making it green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Console.Clear() to clear the current contents of the Console.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

For instance

```
static double InputFuel()
{
    double fFuel;
    string text;
    bool badValue = true;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(text, out fFuel) && fFuel >= 20)
        {
            badValue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0} is below the minimum value of 20  \n\n", text);
            Console.Write("Please re-enter number greater than 20 : ");
        }
    } while (badValue);
    return fFuel;
}
```

Comment: This will clear the screen, but not prevent that the first line is re-written, as requested.

Comment: It might not be desirable to clear the console of all text. This is a sledgehammer where a chisel is more appropriate.

Comment: Clearing the whole screen of text is actually what the OP said - whether or not that was what the question was meant to be "How can I make it not to show first write statement ??"

Comment: @C.Knight no, I don't think that is what the OP means when he stated "How can I make it not to show first write statement ??". Which makes sense, because in the original code, the output would be `"Please re-enter number greater than 20 : Enter amount of fuel used in litres :"` when the code looped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the loop into *infinite* one; if question should be stated just *once* pull it out of the loop:

```
    Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");

    while (true) {
        text = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!double.TryParse(text, out fFuel)) 
            Console.Write("Please re-enter number in correct format: ");
        else if (fFuel <= 0)
            Console.Write("Please re-enter number greater than 0 : "); 
        else if (fFuel >= 20)
            Console.Write("Please re-enter number less than 20 : ");
        else
            break;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static double InputFuel()
    {
        double fFuel;
        string text;
        bool badValue = true;
        bool notFirst = false;
        do
        {
            if(!notFirst)
                Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");
            notFirst = true;
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(text, out fFuel) && fFuel >= 20)
            {
                badValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0} is below the minimum value of 20  \n\n", text);
                Console.Write("Please re-enter number greater than 20 : ");
            }
        } while (badValue);
        return fFuel;
    }
```

Comment: Given it is the first thing in your loop and you only ever do it on the first time through it will be a lot cleaner code to just put that write outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your problem is only an algorithmic problem :

```
static double InputFuel()
    {
        double fFuel;
        string text;
        bool badValue = true;
        Console.Write("Enter amount of fuel used in litres : ");
        do
        {
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(text, out fFuel) && fFuel >= 20)
            {
                badValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0} is below the minimum value of 20  \n\n", text);
                Console.Write("Please re-enter number greater than 20 : ");
            }
        } while (badValue);
        return fFuel;
    }//end InputTemp
```

By putting out the first write out of the loop, it only shows the first time and then does not come again. If you want it to completely disappear, just add a `Console.Clear();` in the else statement to erase what was displayed before, and it's done.

Comment: why are you both clearing the console *and* only writing the text once?

Comment: The Console.clear() is not mandatory as I stated it. But if I understood correctly, he is bothered by the fact that the "Enter amount of fuel used" statement is shown again when a bad input is given, it is natural to put it outside the loop, right?